# Extract semi-structured information from a string in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have sentences such as:

> "[Paris:location] and [Lyon:location] are in France"

And I need to extract all the tagged parts ("Paris:location" and "Lyon:location") from them.

I've tried this code that uses a regular expression (`RegExp`):

```
var regexEntity = new RegExp('\[.+:.+\]', 'g');

var text = '[Paris:location] and [Lyon:location] are in France';
while ((match = regexEntity.exec(text))) {
    console.log(match);
}
```

But this is the output I get, as if it was detecting the colon:

```
[ ':',
  index: 6,
  input: '[Paris:location] and [Lyon:location] are in France' ]
[ ':',
  index: 26,
  input: '[Paris:location] and [Lyon:location] are in France' ]
```

Is there something wrong with my regular expression? Any other approach you'd use to get that info?

Comment: First of all, if you planned to use a constructor, you had to use `var regexEntity = new RegExp('\\[.+:.+\\]', 'g');`. However, if you used a regex literal notation, this problem would not exist. Note that `'\[.+:.+\]'` = `'[.+:.+]'` (effectively matches 1 symbol - `.`, `+`, or `:`). Then, `.+` is a greedy subpattern, you could use lazy `+?`. Then, you could add capturing groups.

Comment: That's why I avoid using `RegExp` constructor. Whenever using RegExp constructor to construct RegEx, log the regex before using it.

Comment: Can I know why this question got 5 downvotes? I'm not aware of it and I'd like to avoid repeating the same mistake again. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.+` is greedy, you will need to use the lazy version of it: `.+?`.

Then, it is simple like this:

```
var text = '[Paris:location] and [Lyon:location] are in France';
console.log(text.match(/\[.+?:.+?\]/g));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regular expression with a non lazy search and positive lookahead.

```js
var regex = /\[(.*?)(?=:location)/gi,
    string = '"[Paris:location] and [Lyon:location] are in France"',
    match;
 
while ((match = regex.exec(string)) !== null) {
    console.log(match[1]);
}
```